# Call Application.OnTime with fully qualified path to sub?

Tags: vba, excel, timer

I have a spreadsheet that I implemented a timer in to automatically update a formula every 10 seconds.  Everything was working great until I would open another spreadsheet.  My assumption was that it was still trying to run `Timer()` on the wrong sheet.  So, I tried switching to absolute calls.  Here is my full code:

```
Dim TimerActive As Boolean
Sub StartTimer()
    Start_Timer
End Sub
Private Sub Start_Timer()
    TimerActive = True
    Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "timetrack.xlsm!Tracker.Timer"
End Sub
Sub Stop_Timer()
    TimerActive = False
End Sub
Sub Timer()
    Dim tracker As Worksheet
    Set tracker = Workbooks("timetrack.xlsm").Sheets("Tracker")
    tracker.Range("O1").Value = "Timer Stopped"
    'On Error Resume Next
    If TimerActive Then
        tracker.Range("O2").Value = Time
        Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:10"), "timetrack.xlsm!Tracker.Timer"
        tracker.Range("N:N").Calculate
    End If
    tracker.Range("O1").Value = ""
End Sub
```

Specifically, I'm getting an error on the `Application.OnTime` line:

> Cannot run the macro ''S:\OneDrive...!docs\timetrack.xlsm'!Tracker.Timer'. The macro may not be available in this workbook or all macros may be disabled.

The path that shows up in the error is correct.  What is wrong?  What's weird is it seems to run it in the `StartTimer()` sub without issue.

Comment: I am not able to duplicate the problem. I can open and work in another workbook while a workbook using your code is working behind it. (Excel 2016, Win 10)

Answer (score 1):

To refer to a procedure in a worksheet, you need to use the `WorkSheet.CodeName` and not the `WorkSheet.Name` :

```
Application.OnTime Now() + TimeValue("00:00:10"), ThisWorkbook.Name & "!" & Me.CodeName & ".Timer"
```

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to activate the desired workbook prior to making changes to the cells within.

Before accessing the contents within the workbook, try adding:

```
Workbooks("timetrack.xlsm").Activate
```

If the macro that runs is in "timetrack.xlsm" you could also use the following code to avoid referencing the workbook name:

```
ThisWorkbook.Activate
```

ThisWorkbook refers to the workbook in which the macro resides.

Comment: What exactly does activating it do?  If it switches focus, this is not an option.

Comment: It does switch focus, but you could store the active workbook as a workbook and activate that as the last step in the macro. Any reason you can't change focus.